# immediately invoked functions Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code

```
(function () {
    $(function () {
        JaPost.fixedHeight = $('.header').outerHeight();
    });
})();
```

Should I be nesting the jquery document ready $(function () inside an immediately invoked function? Is this customary practice? or not necessary?

I also have the following code

```
(function () {
    // Javascript that needs to be run regardless of whether the document is ready 

    $(function () {
        Javascript run when the document is ready
    });
})();
```

How do we deal with immediately invoked functions and JQuery?

Comment: It just creates a new context, if you don't need it, don't use it,

Comment: I'm wondering why would you, it would take the point away of a `document.ready`, might as well not even have it.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek What exactly are you talking about?

Comment: does the document.ready function create  a new context?

Comment: `context` within `.ready()` handler is `document`

Comment: Every function does that. The ready's callback does that. You should actually have asked what does an immediately invoked function do instead of asking do you I need it.

Comment: @Vohuman From the OP's comment they want to call the `document.ready` right away even if it's not. The outer function might as well not be there, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek _"From the OP's comment they want to call the document.ready right away even if it's not. "_ Which comment ? Cannot call `.ready()` with `$(document).ready()` ; `ready()` is `event` . Though can hold , release `.ready()` event utilizing `$.holdReady()`

Comment: @guest271314 Their code comment `// Javascript that needs to be run regardless of whether the document is ready `. Please clarify your comment, it doesn't make any sense. I never said anything about calling `.ready()`, `document.ready` is just short hand for mentioning `$(document).ready(...)`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek You are correct. Did not notice comment at OPs `js` . Perhaps not interpret _"From the OP's comment they want to call the `document.ready` right away even if it's not. "_ correctly ? that is, portion at "they want to call the `document.ready`"

Comment: @PotaOnasys Just was alerted to comment , which did not notice here , initially . Is requirement for function that needs to be called regardless of whether document is ready be completed before `.ready()` called ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to wrap your DOM ready `$(function () {` into an IIFE.

Additionally, to make sure another library will not mess with the `$` namespace you could:

```
jQuery(function( $ ){  // DOM ready and $ alias "secured"
   $("p").hide();
});
```

so **no need to**, but you *can* wrap your jQuery DOM ready into an IIFE like:

```
(jQuery(function( $ ){  // DOM ready and $ alias "secured"
   $("p").hide();
})());
```

---

If you have other JS code with variable names that might collide with other unknown code, than wrapping everything you provide into an IIFE **is a great idea:**

```
// OTHER JS CODE
var arr = "Arrrrrgh!"   // <<< notice the missing ";"

;(function () { // IIFE with leading ; to prevent errors (fn execu.) on missing ;

    var arr = [1, 2];

    $(function () {       // DOM ready
        $("p").hide();    // Cool we're hidden now
        console.log(arr); // [1, 2]
    });

}());

console.log(arr); // "Arrrrrgh!"
```